# Solving system of coupled differential non linear equations using finite difference method?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to model a tubular reactor using the finite difference method based on the following governing equations:

$$ -V_z \dfrac {\partial C_A}{\partial z} + D \dfrac {\partial ^2 C_A}{\partial z^2} - k_1C_AC_B = 0$$

$$ -V_z \dfrac {\partial C_B}{\partial z} + D \dfrac {\partial ^2 C_B}{\partial z^2} - k_1C_AC_B- k_2C_BC_C = 0$$

$$ -V_z \dfrac {\partial C_C}{\partial z} + D \dfrac {\partial ^2 C_C}{\partial z^2} + k_1C_AC_B -k_2C_BC_C = 0$$

$$ -V_z \dfrac {\partial C_D}{\partial z} + D \dfrac {\partial ^2 C_D}{\partial z^2} + k_2C_BC_C = 0$$

With simulation parameters of:

$$L=10; V_z=1; D=10^{-4}; k_1=k_2=1;$$
$$C_{A0}=C_{B0}=1; C_{C0}=C_{C0}=0 $$

However, after discretisation of the system, I am unsure of how to solve the system due to the non linear reaction terms in each equation (i.e. $k_1C_AC_B$ etc.).

Are there suggestions to help solve this?

Comment: The fourth equation you can solve independently once you know the other concentrations.  Now, look at the first three.  What is $d/dz (C_A+C_B+C_C+C_D)$?  My guess is that it would be zero due to conservation of mass.  Does this help simplify the system?

Comment: You do not have enough data to solve the problem... You would have to know, for instance, $C'_{A0}, C'_{B0}, C'_{C0}, +C'_{D0}$. For the simulation you also need to know the advection coefficient $V_z$.

Comment: Also, are you certain of the signs in the reaction terms?

Comment: My mistake, $V_z$ is known. I have edited the post to show this. And yes, the reaction terms all have the correct sign ($A+B \to C$ and $C+B \to D$).

Comment: You need a second boundary condition for each variable. This could be at the other end of the reactor or it could be a flux at the bottom.

Comment: You also would be well-served by changing basis to one in which one of the variables is the total mass, and then tracking the evolution of the other three variables in the basis. This would ensure that the numerics don't destroy the mass conservation.